# Initialize a variable once and for all

Tags: java, android, initialization

I am developing an `Android` application, that contains a class called `userFunctions`.
All it's functions use a function called `getIP()` that defines the IP address to use:

```
public class UserFunctions {

    private JSONParser jsonParser;

    private static String loginURL = "/android_login_api/";
    private static String mplayerURL = "/android_mplayer_api/";
    private static String registerURL = "/android_login_api/";

    private static String login_tag = "login";
    private static String register_tag = "register";
    private static String delete_tag = "delete";
    private static String update_tag = "update";
    private static String music_tag = "music";
    private static String getusers_tag = "getusers";


    // constructor
    public UserFunctions(){
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }

    public String getIP(){
        if(isConnectedToServer("192.168.1.2", 500)==false)
        {
            if(isConnectedToServer("www.google.com", 500)==true)
            {
                ReadEmails re = new ReadEmails();
                return re.processMail();
            }
        }
        return "192.168.1.2";
    }



    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://"+this.getIP()+loginURL, params);
        // return json
        Log.i("JSON", json.toString());
        return json;
    }
    public JSONObject deleteUser(String email){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", delete_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://"+this.getIP()+loginURL, params);
        // return json
        Log.i("JSON", json.toString());
        return json;
    }

    public JSONObject updateUser(String email, String field, String value){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", update_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("field", field));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value", value));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://"+this.getIP()+loginURL, params);
        // return json
        Log.i("JSON", json.toString());
        return json;
    }



    public boolean isConnectedToServer(String url, int timeout) {
        try{
            URL myUrl = new URL(url);
            URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
            connection.connect();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle your exceptions
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param name
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String mode, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mode", mode));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://"+this.getIP()+registerURL, params);
        // return json
        return json;
    }






    public JSONObject PlayMusic(String name){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "play"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://"+this.getIP()+mplayerURL, params);
        // return json
        return json;
    }

    public JSONObject ChangeVol(String volume){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "volume"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("volume", volume));
        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://"+this.getIP()+mplayerURL, params);
        // return json
        return json;
    }

    public JSONObject StopMusic(){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "stop"));
        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://"+this.getIP()+mplayerURL, params);
        // return json
        return json;
    }


    public JSONObject ParcourirMusic(){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "parcourir"));
        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://"+this.getIP()+mplayerURL, params);
        // return json
        return json;
    }


    /**
     * Function get Login status
     * */
    public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        int count = db.getRowCount();
        if(count > 0){
            // user logged in
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Function to logout user
     * Reset Database
     * */
    public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        db.resetTables();
        return true;
    }




    public void ReadMail(){

    try{
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "rami.mtiri@gmail.com", "Rambo_007");
    Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);


    SearchTerm term = new SearchTerm() {
      @Override
      public boolean match(Message mess) {
        try {
          return mess.getContent().toString().toLowerCase().indexOf("boston") != -1;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
         // Logger.getLogger(JavaMailTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
         // Logger.getLogger(JavaMailTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return false;
      }
    };

    Message[] searchResults = inbox.search(term);
    for(Message m:searchResults){
        Log.e("mail",m.getFrom()[0].toString() );
      System.out.println("MATCHED: " + m.getFrom()[0]);

    }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    }

}
```

I almost use the functions of this class in every activity so I run the test every time I use one of these functions.
I would like to know if there is a method to initialise the IP address once and for all in the beginning of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First, which is more OOP is make a Util class and just put the method in there. and call UtilClass.getIp(); everytime you use it.
2. The first thing that happens when your Application and that you have access to is, Application.onCreate(); You can initlize your variable their, make it public static so you can use YourApp.method.
3. Another way is to extend Activity class, have all your Activiy inherit that method.

Comment: thanks wtsang02 i want to do the test just once so i think i will test the second option. i will tell you what happened ;)

Comment: Make sure you eclare your subclassed Application in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

declare a final String.  set it in the constructor.